# How to move along depth axis on a mac?

Tags: 3d-view

If I want to move the user view in Mac, I can do it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd>. Note that I just have a trackpad, not a mouse. Anyway, the problem is that this way I can just move along two axes. To make this clear I took a video, which you can see [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=768CF89E7CF13325!5476&authkey=!AMPdyrTLRKVm8zc&ithint=video%2Cmov).

Like you see in the video I can only move just along the Y and Z axes, not along the X axis. If I wanted to move the user view in order to look at the back of the cube. I had first to rotate the camera and then move the visual again, which is doable but it's not fast/comfortable at all. I need a way (possibly a shortcut) to move the user view along the X axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You track forward/backward the same way that you scroll a web page. Often, a trackpad does this this with a two-finger drag up and down.

Note, that even when this works correctly, it will still not allow you to view the back side of the cube. By default, it will track toward an invisible pivot point i the center of the view. As it approaches that point, the track will become slower and slower, so that you never go past that point.

If you want to view the opposite side of you cube, you will have to rotate. But there is a setting that makes this a little easier. In User Preferences in the Interface tab, turn on "Rotate Around Selection."

[image]

This will force the view to orbit whatever object you have selected, instead of orbiting the center of the view. This will make it MUCH easier to just rotate around to the other side of an object. Check out the other options there, as many of them are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer to work, you will need to enable something in the *User Preferences*. Go to *File > User Preferences... > Input* and check *Emulate Numpad* at the middle left, if it isn't already. From here, you can key <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, or <kbd>7</kbd> to rotate the view around. From one of these rotated views, you can surely do what you've been doing, except this time along the *X-axis*.

**Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, or <kbd>7</kbd> will rotate 180 degrees opposite plain <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, or <kbd>7</kbd>.**

Comment: So the only way is to rotate around my object? isn't there a way to directly move towards the object?

Comment: With a mouse, you could scroll. I don't think there is a way with just a trackpad. Also, if my answer helped, please consider accepting it.